# Splitting string values with more than 4 values in sql query in SQL server 16

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split string "val=ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR" in to different column values and Parsename function is not accepting split criteria with more than 4 splits.

This values are coming from Table and needed to implement the function using  SQL fucntions if possible.

`PARSENAME(replace(val,'_','.'),4) as col1` and returning null. How can i split this value?

Comment: Do you mean "MySQL", the open source database now owned by Oracle, or "Microsoft SQL Server"? Currently, your title mentions one, but the tags mention the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2016 I have implemented two query below. Query#1 will split the string into rows with `string_split()` function. Query#2 will split the string into columns with `string_split()` and dynamic pivot technique.

Create table and insert statements:

```
 create table testtable (teststring varchar(50));
 insert into testtable values('ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR');
```

Query#1

```
 select  row_number()over(order by (select null)) rn, [value] as Street1 from testtable 
    cross apply string_split(teststring,'_')
```

| rn | Street1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | DEF |
| 3 | GHI |
| 4 | JKL |
| 5 | MNO |
| 6 | PQR |

Or without row number it's just :

```
select   [value] as Street1 from testtable 
   cross apply string_split(teststring,'_')
```

Query#2:

```
 DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
 DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';


 with cte as
 (
  select  row_number()over(order by (select null)) rn, [value] as Street1 from testtable 
  cross apply string_split(teststring,'_')
 )
 select  @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + quotename(rn)
             FROM cte
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,1,'')
         
 set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
 (
    select  row_number()over(order by (select null)) rn, [value] as Street1 from testtable 
    cross apply string_split(teststring,''_'')
 ) src
 pivot 
 (
     max(street1) for rn in (' + @cols + ')
 ) piv'
 
 
 execute(@query)
```

Output:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL | MNO | PQR |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c73eb7538a6c4182f32e8249c8ec3ab4)*

If you are using MySQL 8.0 then with recursive common table expression you can easily split this to rows :

```
 create table testtable (teststring varchar(50));
 insert into testtable values('ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR');
```

Query:

```
 with RECURSIVE cte (street1,level)as
 (
 select SUBSTRING_INDEX(teststring, '_', 1) AS street1, 1 as level
 from testtable
 
 union all
 
 select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(teststring, "_", level+1), "_", -1),level+1
 from cte inner join testtable t 
 on cte.street1<SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(teststring, "_", level+1), "_", -1)
 )
 select street1 from cte
```

Outupt:

| street1 |
| --- |
| ABC |
| DEF |
| GHI |
| JKL |
| MNO |
| PQR |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e36620279938ca91c74fc2775898840b)*

Comment: Awesome! it works. Also, will it be possible that value can be used based on index like in parsename. Suppose i have splitted ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR and want to use GHI as value of new column always. Will it be possible with String_Split?
Well i am acheiving it very hard via Substrings:

SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(value,PATINDEX('%F[_]%',value),100),3,100),0,
   CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(value,PATINDEX('%F[_]%',value),100),3,100))

Answer (score 0):

**SUBSTRING_INDEX** is your goal.

```
set @val="ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR" ;


select
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 1) as no1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 2), "_", -1) as no2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 3), "_", -1) as no3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 4), "_", -1) as no4,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 5), "_", -1) as no5,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 6), "_", -1) as no6;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select @val;
+-------------------------+
| @val                    |
+-------------------------+
| ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL_MNO_PQR |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> 
MariaDB [bernd]> 
MariaDB [bernd]> select
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 1) as no1,
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 2), "_", -1)as no2,
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 3), "_", -1)as no3,
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 4), "_", -1)as no4,
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 5), "_", -1)as no5,
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, "_", 6), "_", -1)as no6;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| no1  | no2  | no3  | no4  | no5  | no6  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ABC  | DEF  | GHI  | JKL  | MNO  | PQR  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: The values are coming from table . And it won't assign multiple values to varibale. I guess loop is required.Can you pls help on this. Also, can it be done using only SQL functions? but not pl/SQL

Comment: YES! -  replace **@val** to **val** . this was only a sample. you not post the Query, so i cant correct it. post the wanted out and your query

Comment: Can we do without pl/SQL?